# How to add a field from a struct to an array?

Tags: c++

In my homework, I have to build a program using a struct with some fields. I have to output a list with the name of the "societate" field in an ascending order and the number of these fields.

So I tried to add all these fields into a new array while checking if the field is not already inside that array.

Here's how I tried to do it:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

struct sponsorizari {
    char societate[30], localitate[30];
    int cod_sponsorizare, data, valoare;
};

int main()
{
    int n, k = 0;
    char a[100];
    sponsorizari x[100];
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin.get();
        cin.get(x[i].societate, 30);
        cin.get();
        cin.get(x[i].localitate, 30);
        cin.get();
        cin >> x[i].cod_sponsorizare >> x[i].data >> x[i].valoare;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            if (!strcmp(a[j], x[i].societate))
            {
                strcpy(a[k], x[i].societate);
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't work - it gives me some errors.
How can I make it work?

[image: Edit: compiler errors]

Comment: "It doesn't work - it gives me some errors" This is very vague. Compiler errors? Runtime errors? Wrong output? Can you narrow down where the errors are coming from by removing irrelevant code?

Comment: why are you using `char[]` over `std::string`?

Comment: @RyanHaining I edited my original post with the errors. I'm using char because that's what I learnt in school for now.

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. In addition, the text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wandbox link for the curious](https://wandbox.org/permlink/X4omZjJgaK2Solh3)

The problem comes down to the uses of `a` in these two lines

```
if (!strcmp(a[j], x[i].societate)) {
    strcpy(a[k], x[i].societate);
    //...
```

`a` is a `char[]`, when you do `a[j]` that is giving you a single `char` back. You can't copy a `char*` (string) to a `char`. I suspect what you want is to simply use `a` here

```
if (!strcmp(a, x[i].societate)) {
    strcpy(a, x[i].societate);
    //...
```

---

Though I'm lost on most of this code. You are checking if they are the same, and then if they are the same copying from one to the other?

You never put anything in `a` to begin with.

You initialize `k` to `0` before starting your inner loop `for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)` - and since `k` is `*` here this will never run. I can't tell what the purpose of the inner loop is supposed to be but it looks like it doesn't belong

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (!strcmp(a, x[i].societate)) {
        ++count;
    }
}
```

In response to your problem statement, here is an outline of what your approach should be

```
unique_strings = []  // initially empty

for (each sponsorizari sp in x) {
    unique = true; // assume s it's unique
    for (each str in unique_strings) {
        if (sp.societate == str)
            unique = false; // found a match, not unique
            break;
        }
    }
    if (unique) { // we got through all unique_strings without a match
       add sp.societate to unique_strings
    }
}
```

If this is for a class I seriously suggest you go to office hours because you are clearly very lost.

Comment: I'm checking if they are not the same, if they aren't it should copy the "societate" field into that array. At first it is empty, but then it should add them one by one. (a[k], k++ - that's why I put it there).

Comment: My mistake is that I didn't realise the for loop will never be executed because j will never be less than k. So I think in this case the second for loop should be replaced with a do - while. Am I right?

Comment: `strcmp` returns 0 if the two arguments are the same `if (!strcmp(...))` is true only if they are equal.

Comment: I don't know what you mean "add them one by one" are you trying to accumulate a list of all the strings which don't match the one before them in the array?

Comment: if you want an array of `100` strings you'd want `char a[100][30]`

Comment: I wanted to add all the "societate" fields from the struct into an array if they aren't already. With that, I'm checking if the field is already into the array - if it isn't, strcpy should add it into the array.

Comment: I see, you're looking to make an array of all the unique `societate`s, is that right?

Comment: Yes. That's what I tried to tell you from the beginning haha. I explained in the above comments how I wanted to do it.

Comment: difficult to tell because your code is trying to do something very different. I added some pseudocode to the bottom of my answer, but there is no straightforward path from what you have posted to a working program. The only option would be to write the whole program for you, but that's not the purpose of this site.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, thanks for helping me out. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution for the problem illustrated by you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

struct sponsorizari {
    string societate, localitate;
    int cod_sponsorizare, data, valoare;
};

int main()
{
    int n, count = 0;
    unordered_map<string,int> stringMap;
    cout<<"Enter Value of n"<<endl;
    cin >> n;
    sponsorizari x[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter societate "<<i<<endl;
        cin>>x[i].societate;
        cout<<"Enter localitate "<<i<<endl;
        cin>>x[i].localitate;
        cout<<"Enter cod_sponsorizare "<<i<<endl;
        cin>>x[i].cod_sponsorizare;
        cout<<"Enter data "<<i<<endl;
        cin>>x[i].data;
        cout<<"Enter valoare "<<i<<endl;
        cin>>x[i].valoare;
        stringMap[(x[i].societate)]++;
    }
    cout<<"Among the n input societate's, the unique societate's are"<<endl;
    for (auto x : stringMap) 
    {
        if(x.second==1)
        {
            cout<<x.first<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.